# The purpose of the "for more info visit Meta" link on locked posts

Tags: support, locked-posts

[image]

I have seen this many times, even when a post is actually being discussed on Meta. Yet the link just goes to the main Meta feed - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/. There is no actual "info" there relevant to the question that is locked.

If anything, it seems to me to just point people towards another place that they can complain about things. Is this link ever useful? What is the expected outcome from directing people to Meta?

Comment: Yes, what you said: *"just [to] point people towards another place that they can complain about things"*. If you want to complain about the post being locked, go complain on Meta by asking a question about it. The "post notice" banner text is not directly editable by moderators, so there's no good way of making it link to an existing Meta discussion. And when there *isn't* an existing Meta discussion, then what would you do?

Comment: See also, on the global Meta: [Can we do something about misleading message and link on locked questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141669), [Have locked question directly link to its respective meta discussion if existing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190482), ["Post Locked" should link to the meta FAQ on post locking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173624)

Comment: @CodyGray a dupe I guess but I was looking in the wrong places